# Mathematica: why 3D plot remember last viewpoint/rotation made to it, even after evaluating again?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I find this a bit annoying.

I make a 3D plot, initially it come up in the default orientation. Then, using the mouse, I rotate it some way.

Now I run the command again, expecting to obtain the original shape (i.e the original orientation before I rotated it by mouse), but instead, it just gives me the same plot I have on the screen, i.e. it seems to have kept/remembered the last viewpoint in that output cell.

I wanted it to go back to the original viewpoint. So, I delete the output cell to make it happen.

Do you think this is how it is supposed to work? Having to keep deleting the cell output is annoying when I am trying thing. I think it should go back to original default orientation.

```
  Graphics3D[ Cuboid[{-.1,-.1,-.1},{.1,.1,.1}],
        AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},
        PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}},
        Axes->True,
        AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"},
        Ticks->None]
```

If you run the above, then move the plot, then run the command again, you'll see what I mean.

version 8.0.01

EDIT:

More strange: I added viewpoint option to force it to the default view point, yet, the same result. It remember the last viewpoint. This below is the default viewpoint, from help.

```
 Graphics3D[ Cuboid[{-.1,-.1,-.1},{.1,.1,.1}],
        AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},
        PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}},
        Axes->True,
        AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"},
        ViewPoint->{1.3,-2.4,2},
        Ticks->None]
```

I find this strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
With PreserveImageOptions->False, settings for image options from the previous
version of a graphic are always ignored.
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. But I still find it strange behaviour, because one expects the command to give the same output each time it is issued. cheers

Comment: I actually like this behaviour, because then I can interactively orient it the way I want, and work on improving some aspect of the graphics in that view and see the results update. It would be cumbersome if I had to reorient it every time.

Comment: @Yoda, Yes, but I meant the option should be the other way round! I mean, the default should be to preserve is FALSE, and if one wants to do as you want, then they should be using the option. i.e. the logic is reversed. One expects a command to generate the same output, and not be affected by history. Unless otherwise.

Comment: @Nasser If you spend a lot of time trying to get the Plot looking pretty, and then loss all the work, you may think different. This way your work is never lost, unless you specifically state that.

Answer (score 5):

In a Mathematica notebook, render your plot, then orient it the way you like.

Then place the cursor on the left of the PLOT OUTPUT, and type "AbsoluteOptions["
Then place the cursor on the right of the PLOT OUTPUT, and type "]" Shift-Enter

You will get a bunch of information. Look for ViewPoint and then use this as an option in your graphics. Then, you will always get the same orientation.

Comment: thanks!, I used to remember this trick and I forgot it, thanks for reminding me about it. Useful to know current Viewpoint.

Answer (score 3):

I like to think of re-running the Plot command as updating the graphic I have already created.  After all, it does not make a second plot.

From this perspective, if I rotate or size my graphic, I do not want *Mathematica* to mess with that when I add a label or change a style.

However, if I **delete my graphic** to start over, *Mathematica* uses the default rotation and size.

Therefore, I find the behavior logical and appreciated.