# How to force Plot to use the specificed ImageSize in 3D when using the mouse to rotate an image

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

(*Mathematica* version: 8.0.4, on Windows 7)

Could someone please remind me how to tell M not to change the ImageSize in the following case:

I have a Manipulate, where I make a grid, and inside the grid, I either show one plot, or 2 plots, depending on a control choice.

To keep the overall displayed image the same, then if I am displaying one plot I use one size, and if I am displaying 2 plots, I use half the length for each plot. Easy enough so far.

The strange thing is that when I use the mouse to rotate the one plot case, and then switch back to 2 plots, the plot size now does not use the ImageSize I specified.

It seems by using the mouse to rotate one plot, it affected the next plot shown on the same screen location.

Using `SphericalRegion -> True` or not, has no effect. Using `RotationAction -> "Fit"` has no effect.

Here is a small example of what I mean, and then I show how I currently solve this problem. But I solve it by using GraphicsGrid in place of Grid. I wanted to keep using Grid if possible.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{opt = {Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All}, p,
   size, data = Table[RandomReal[], {10}, {10}], wid = 300, len = 300},

  size = If[choice == 1, {wid, len}, {wid, len/2}];
  Print[size];
  p = ListPlot3D[data,SphericalRegion->True,ImagePadding -> 10,ImageSize ->size];

  If[choice == 1,
   Grid[{{p}}, Sequence@opt], Grid[{{p}, {p}}, Sequence@opt]
   ]
  ],

 Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[choice], {1, 2}]}],
 {{choice, 2}, None}
 ]
```

To reproduce the problem, is simple: first I note the size, this is how I want to keep it. Now I click on choice 1, now using the mouse I rotate the one plot. Now I click on choice 2 to go back, then I see the plot size is not what I expected it to be.

[image]

I am sure it is an option I need to use. Just have not found it yet.

ps. Actually what seems to happen, is that the SAME plot that was rotated, stays on the content area, and was used in place of one of the 2 plots in the second case. Very strange. I must be doing something silly somewhere, as this is too strange.

**Update 2:48 am**
This is in response to using `Dynamic` in the Manipulate expression as shown below by MrWizard. On V 8.04, it does not work. Here is the code:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{p, size, data = Table[RandomReal[], {10}, {10}], wid = 300, 
   len = 300},

  size = If[choice == 1, {wid, len}, {wid, len/2}];
  p = ListPlot3D[data, SphericalRegion -> True, ImagePadding -> 10, 
    ImageSize -> size];

  If[choice == 1,
   Grid[{{p}}],
   Dynamic@Grid[{{p}, {p}}]
   ]
  ],

 Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[choice], {1, 2}]}],
 {{choice, 2}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

**Update 3:03 am**

This below works by keeping the Grid. Adding a Frame around the grid makes it works.
(Thanks to Mike answer showing that using Frame instead of Grid made it work, I figured let me try to add a Frame around the Grid)

One of the strangest things I've seen using Mathematica for long time :)

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{p, size, data = Table[RandomReal[], {10}, {10}], wid = 300, 
   len = 300},

  size = If[choice == 1, {wid, len}, {wid, len/2}];
  p = ListPlot3D[data, SphericalRegion -> True, ImagePadding -> 10, 
    ImageSize -> size];

  If[choice == 1,
   Framed@Grid[{{p}}],
   Grid[{{p}, {p}}]
   ]
  ],

 Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[choice], {1, 2}]}],
 {{choice, 2}, None}
 ]
```

Thanks

Comment: I seem to recall seeing something like this before, but I cannot find it.  I think the solution may have been to use GraphicsGrid, but you don't want that.  You can get the behavior I think you want by adding `Dynamic` to the second `Grid`, but I don't really understand what is happening here, so I need to explore this.

Comment: Mr.Wizard, yes, `GraphicsGrid` won't work. Can't rotate with mouse. As for other comment about adding `Dynamic` to second `Grid`, I am not sure I understand now. Where?, tried, not getting it to work. Thanks.

Comment: At least in v7, it works to make the line read: `Grid[{{p}}, Sequence@opt], Dynamic@Grid[{{p}, {p}}, Sequence@opt]`  -- also, `Sequence@x` is equivalent to `x`; you probably want `Sequence @@ x`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, in V 8.04, adding `Dyanmic` as you showed does not work. I am adding update now so you can see. As for the `Sequence` comment, will look into it. I can remove that, not needed any way. thanks.

Comment: I just found a hack to keep the grid and make it work! Thanks to Mike answer, I simply put a `Frame` around the `Grid` and now it works!! amazing. Please see update.

Comment: See my answer below for my conjecture about this, and also other options you might use (Style, Item, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to another puzzle re how//why Plot3D remembers image options [why does Plot3D remember...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6181944/990168). The solution happens to be the same in this case too: that is, add `PreserveImageOptions -> False` as an option to `Plot3D`. Somehow, the hacks like the ones suggested by MrW and Mike force Plot3D to "forget".

Comment: +1 how do you like that! I knew there was an option ! in back of my mind I had a feeling there was an option. The question you linked to was asked by me as well sometime ago, and I forgot all about. Thanks, I think your solution is the correct one. I think everyone will agree on that.

Comment: @Nasser just noticed that it was your question:) How quickly we forget,huh?

Comment: I think M is so complicated and with do many options, I do not think it is possible to remember them and specially the interactions between them all. What is really needed is some sort of automated tool which runs over the code, and looks up a knowledge/expert system database of collected possible problems, and flag the user for possible problems/issues/watch out type of thing, in the code. For example, not having `PreserveImageOptions -> False` in a 3D type of plot could be flaged, and so on. user can look up this report later. something like Lint for C in a way.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps, as an alternative to waiting for version 10.x and as @MrW suggested in a comment on a related question [http://stackoverflow.com/q/8625296/990168], the new Mathematica SE site will provide nice workspace for the community to take up this and similar challenges as shared projects.

Comment: I hadn't used this option before. Interesting. Reading `ref/PreserveImageOptions` I am still unclear why the default setting should be causing this behaviour and why wrapping the graphic in `Framed` would be a fix (i.e. a fix without explicitly setting the option to `False`).

Comment: @Mike, actually this behavior (that is, default value of the option set to `True`) is considered a nice feature by many (e.g. see the comments in the related question link) including myself.  I think the real issue here is that if you want to keep `PreserveImageOptions->True`, once you wrap a `Graphics3D` object with anything other than `Identity` or `Show` then this 'feature'is lost. Hence a new question: How do you keep this option from being reset to `False` when the `Plot3D` object lives inside a `Panel`,`Frame`,`Pane` etc?

Comment: @kguler I thought default was `Automatic` and it was based on the description of how `Automatic` works that I didn't understand how `Framed` would be controlling this.

Comment: Nice work (+1).  Despite understanding the former topic you linked to, as evidenced by my own answer to it, I did not see this as being the result of the same situation.

Comment: @Mike, I think we should post this as a new question.

Comment: @MrWizard, thank you. It seems like I am not the only one puzzled by the way image options and wrappers interact. Would it be proper SO etiquette to post a new question on this?

Comment: IMHO, yes.  Also, I did not see your comment sooner because `@MrWizard` does not notify me; you need `@Mr.Wizard` or just `@Mr.W`

Comment: Does not work with `ComplexPlot3D` today.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got long but the use of `Grid` seems to be the main thing messing this up, though I haven't had time to identify how/why. If you replace the `If` statement with this:

```
If[choice == 1, Framed@p, Grid[{{p}, {p}}, Sequence@opt]]
```

then it works fine. There are some other things going on in the code that don't seem optimal at first glance but I have just focussed on the graphics sizing due to time constraints. This is not intended as an explanation but might help you or someone else figure out why this is behaving like this. Sorry but short on time but thought it was worth posting the observation about `Grid`.

Comment: thanks. Yes that removes the issue. But I really wanted to use Grid, as my actual code is more complicated, and I use grid to get more control of spacings, and other things. Grid is my main building block for everything. But you were able to point the cause of the problem. So I can use this as temporary workaround while trying to find the main cause. But the I think I should still be able to use a Grid. I do not see why not. Btw, this code is just a 5 minute hack just to show the problem I saw with my main code, it is not meant to be optimal :)  Thanks again for help.

Comment: I am starting to think now this can be a bug. I can't see why removing a Grid and adding Frame in place of it make things work. It just makes no sense to me. I need more coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing any actual analysis, here is my conjecture.

I believe this may the result of an optimization technique which observes that the apparent content of the displayed graphic did not change.  I suppose that the key is therefore to make the apparent content different between each graphic that is displayed in each position of the Grid.  Using something like `Identity` will not work as it vanishes from the expression.  However if this conjecture is correct I expect any persistent change to result in an updated graphic.

I have had success using each of these for the first `Grid` expression:

`Grid[{{ Framed@p }}, opt]`

`Grid[{{ Panel@p }}, opt]`

`Grid[{{ Pane@p }}, opt]`

`Grid[{{ {p} }}, opt]`

`Grid[{{ Item@p }}, opt]`

`Grid[{{ Style@p }}, opt]`

Comment: MrWizard, I am still trying to understand your explanation of what causes this. But from a user point view, I have to call this a bug. But I am glad there is a work around, WHILE keeping the grid. Also adding a Frame around the whole Grid works. Please see my edit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nasser it could either be a bug, or the result of a use that was not intended.  I'll wait before passing judgement, but it doesn't seem right to me either.  Time to sleep now.

Comment: MrWizard, I selected your  Item@p to use in my main code to fix this problem, as that was the least intrusive to the current code I have and affected no visual difference. Thanks to you and Mike for the help.